# Passing a var into a selectattr statment in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I am looping through a dict "**aws_ec2_volums_setting**" and i am trying to pass the loop variable `item.id` to a "**selectattr**" statement to get a list that meets the criteria.

```
- name: Set Filters
  set_fact:
    snapshot_list: "{{ ec2_snapshot_facts.snapshots | selectattr('volume_id', 'equalto', vars[item.id] ) | list }}"
  with_items: "{{ aws_ec2_volums_setting }}"
```

if I hardcode the value it works fine:

```
- name: Set Filters
  set_fact:
    snapshot_list: "{{ ec2_snapshot_facts.snapshots | selectattr('volume_id', 'equalto', 'vol-xxxxxxxxx' ) | list }}"
  with_items: "{{ aws_ec2_volums_setting }}"
```

If I ran a debug command to check the value of the var all looks good

```
- name: Check Val
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.id }}"
  with_items: "{{ aws_ec2_volums_setting }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [aws_delete_snapshoot : Set Filters2] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'vol': u'Vol-01', u'id': u'vol-XXXXXX', u'server': u'us-nv-sat-01'}) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "id": "vol-vol-XXXXXX",
        "server": "us-nv-sat-01",
        "vol": "Vol-01"
    },
    "msg": "vol-XXXXXX"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you just need to drop the vars[] and it should work fine. Change vars[item.id] to just item.id.

Try:

```
- name: Set Filters
  set_fact:
    snapshot_list: "{{ ec2_snapshot_facts.snapshots | selectattr('volume_id', 'equalto', item.id ) | list }}"
  with_items: "{{ aws_ec2_volums_setting }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but unfortunately that has not resolved the issue. The result is that "snapshot_list" is empty.

Comment: "beg har pudding" (apologies) ... something completely unrelated stopped it from working. Your suggestion is on the button !